# wicket create a dynamic return class from getHomePage

Tags: session, dynamic, wicket-1.5

I am building a web application using Wicket 1.5. I need to decide if the user that is currently logged in is an admin or a regular user and display different page for each of them.

My code:

```
public class HomePage extends WebApplication {
  private boolean flag = false;

  @Override
  protected void init(){do things}

  @Override
  public Session newSession(Request request, Response response) {
           ... some calculation ...
     return new HomePageWebSession(request);
  } 

  @Override
  public Class<? extends WebPage> getHomePage(){    
     if(flag){
        return Admin.class
     } else return User.class
  }
 }
```

The problem is that `getHomepage` is called before `newSession` and I use newSession to figure out if the user is Admin or not and init the flag.
In addition I see that `getHomePage` is called multiple times before `newSession` is called.
Why is `getHomePage` called multiples times and why is `getHomePage` called before `newSession`?

thanks for any help

Comment: I cannot say much about Wicket 1.5, but I've checked in 6.x and session is being created before any calls to getHomePage(), which is kind of logical.

Comment: you are right i change the version from 1.5.3 to 1.5.8 and its working now